# Travis environment variables not found from python

Tags: python, environment-variables, travis-ci

[This guide](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#default-environment-variables) tells that several environment variable are available to all builds on Travis.

However [my build fails](https://travis-ci.org/raczben/pylinx/jobs/618235607#L421) because the lack of the `TRAVIS` environment variable. (I have printed out the available variables and there is no TRAVIS in them.)

Here is [my travis config](https://travis-ci.org/raczben/pylinx/builds/618235605/config).

What do I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem roots in tox. Tox clears environment variables. Use `passenv=TRAVIS*` to pass the Travis-related environment variables.

[passenv](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#conf-passenv):

> passenv(SPACE-SEPARATED-GLOBNAMES)
>
> New in version 2.0.
>
> A list of wildcard environment variable names which shall be copied from the tox invocation environment to the test environment when executing test commands. If a specified environment variable doesn’t exist in the tox invocation environment it is ignored. You can use * and ? to match multiple environment variables with one name.